# What's wrong with this code? Time does not update

Tags: python, time, pyqt4, maya

This is my code. The code does not give any errors but the problem is that time does not update and 50% of my CPU is taking by maya like maya's "`scriptjob -idle flag`", I hope I will get an answer here whereas I am new to this site for asking questions.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
import sip

def maya_main_window():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)

class RenamingDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent= maya_main_window()):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Clock")
        self.setFixedSize(250, 200)

        self.createLayout()
        self.button_update()

        self.run_time()        

    def run_time(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self, QtCore.SLOT("update_time()"))
        self.timer.start()

    def createLayout(self):
        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Ok")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel("time")

        buttonLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def update_time(self):      
        self.time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        self.updater = QtCore.QString(self.time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))
        self.label.setText(self.updater)

    def button_update(self):
        self.connect(self.button1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.printer)

    def printer(self):
        print "hai",

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dialog = RenamingDialog()
    dialog.show()
```

Thank you.

Comment: improve your question, what exactly your doubt is? where is your problem?

Comment: You should add the current and the expected outputs.

Comment: time is not updating the text remains same (i.e. time) what's the problem in update_time method? hope i understand....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a python slot, you can specify it just by tipping the method: self.update_time. This works for all methods accessible by Python.

```
self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self, QtCore.SLOT("update_time()"))
```

should be

```
self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"), self.update_time)
```

anyway you can use the newer connection way:

```
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_time)
```

if you want to use your original syntax, you have to decorate your method *update_time* with decorator *@pyqtSlot*

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line of code `self.timer.setInterval(1000)` based on your suggestion then it works perfect now my `maya` app is no more taking half of my cpu. Thank you.